# Knockout js checkbox checked binding

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

In knockout js am trying to perform a foreach on an array of data to display check boxes. The issue I am having is that the checked databind does not appear to run until I interact with one of the boxes. For example, below I am generating 5 text boxes none of which are showing up as checked. However when I click "one", "two" and "four" also get checked as they should have been from the beginning.

Javascript:

```
var viewModel = {};

viewModel.choices = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"];
viewModel.selectedChoices = ko.observableArray(["two", "four"]);

viewModel.selectedChoicesDelimited = ko.dependentObservable(function () {
        return viewModel.selectedChoices().join(",");
    });

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="options" data-bind="foreach: choices">
    <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="NotifyMembers" data-bind="checked: $parent.selectedChoices, attr: { value: $data }" /><span data-bind="text: $data"></span></label></li>
</ul>
<hr />
<div data-bind="text: selectedChoicesDelimited"></div>
```

Fiddle is at: http://jsfiddle.net/bvGG3/1/

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In Knockout before version 3.0 the bindings fired in order, so your problem is that your `checked` binding fires before your `attr` binding.

So you need to change the order of your bindings:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="NotifyMembers" 
       data-bind="attr: { value: $data }, checked: $parent.selectedChoices" />
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pLNdc/).

Or your original code will work when you update to 3.0 (demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HhKwX/)).