# How to add new property with same key name inside declared object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, javascript-objects

How can I append/add new property with same key name inside declared object ?

Here the code:

```
// Declared object
var myObject = {
    name : 'John',
    age  : 15,
};

// Array list of new property need to be add to myObject
var others = [
  { key : 'hobby', value: 'reading' },
  { key : 'hobby', value: 'writing' }
];
```

What i've been try so far:

```
ko.utils.arrayForEach(others, function(other) {
    myObject[other.key] = other.value;
});
```

and

```
ko.utils.arrayForEach(others, function(other) {
    var extendObject = new Object();
    extendObject[other.key] = other.value;

    $.extend(myObject, extendObject);
});
```

The result still both doesn't work either. It just replace existing property value

What I need is something like this:

```
myObject: { name: 'John', age: 15, hobby: 'reading', hobby: 'writing' }
```

Please note: I don't want to make it array : `hobby: ['reading', 'writing']`

**UPDATE:**

I was implement this for search functionality, code and details above is simplified version of the part I was stuck.

and here is the full code of what i've try to accomplish:

my views:

```
<form data-bind="submit: $root.getSearchData">
  <input name="date_start" class="datepicker">

  <div class="checkbox">
    <label>
       <input type="checkbox" name="user_id[]" value="1"> John
    </label>
    <label>
       <input type="checkbox" name="user_id[]" value="2"> Michael
    </label>
  </div>
</form>
```

my viewmodels:

```
// Will contains new search property need to append to queryData
self.searchPropertyList = ko.observableArray();

// This function will fetch tasks from server
self.getTasksFromServer = function()
{
   // Query data
   var queryData = {
       sort : 'start',
       order: 'asc'
   };

   /**
    * When getSearchData function fill formData into searchPropertyList observable,
    * this function will get a notify and it will automatically loop through it 
    * and append new property to queryData.
    */
   ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.searchPropertyList(), function(opt)
   {
       queryData[opt.name] = opt.value;
   }

   $.ajax({
       url: 'api/tasks',
       type: 'json',
       data: queryData,
       success: function(data)
       {
       }
   });
}

// Returned form property as array into searchPropertyList observableArray 
// and notify getTaskFromServer function
// This is how formData may look like
// formData = [{ name: 'date_start', value: '2014-08-26' }, { name: 'user_id[]', value: 1 }, { name: 'user_id[]', value: 2 }]; 
self.getSearchData = function(form)
{
     var formData = $(form).serializeArray();

     self.searchPropertyList(formData);
}
```

So, ajax will request something like this:

```
api/tasks?sort=start&order=asc&date_start=2014-08-26&user_id[]=1&user_id[]=2
```

Someone, please help, Thanks :)

Comment: { key : 'hobby', value: 'reading writing' } nad while reading this split the string for " " to get the array of the hobbies. Not really sure if You can have 2 properties with one name.

Comment: You can not have multiple properties with the same name in one object.

Comment: There will never be two properties with the same name in an object. An array seems to be your savior

Comment: is there any other way to accomplish this ?

Comment: Yes there is a way: you need to use an array. But what is your end goal? Why an array is not a solution for you?

Comment: "*Please note: I don't want to make it array : `hobby: ['reading', 'writing']`*" – fair enough, but *why?* Why do you want to complicate your life and not use the correct solution?

Comment: I've update the question, please take a look. Maybe it could explain why I don't want it to be array. Thanks everyone ! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the comments say, you can not have multiple property with the same name.

What you can do this to add the hobby value to the same hobby property and split it when you need all your hobbies:

```
var person = { hobby: "programmer" };

// adding another hobby
person.hobby =+ "-secretary";

var hobbies = person.hobby.split("-"); // [programmer,secretary]
```

Comment: Hi @Misters, thanks for the answer! I've updated my question can you take a look on it ?

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate of

[How can I store multiple values per key in a hash table using Node.JS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19149496/how-can-i-store-multiple-values-per-key-in-a-hash-table-using-node-js)

You have to use {key, [array]} which is hashmap with array as the value and write custom method to push and pop.

Comment: As already mentioned, i don't need the value to be an array. Btw thanks for the answer, can you take a look on my updated question ? maybe you have some other ideas to help me accomplish it ?

Comment: Are you looking for knockoutjs binding checkboxes solution? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18062306/knockout-js-checkbox-checked-binding            Avoid [] in the name. That is not a good practice.

Comment: No i don't need checkboxes directly bind to observable, it will automatically firing my getTasksFromServer function without user manually (click) submit form.

Answer (score 0):

You **cannot add/append same keys** with difference values inside an object but you can **add and extra key** such as below code. By doing this, you can **differentiate the same keys** :

```
// Declared object
var myObject = {
    name : 'John',
    age  : 15,
};

// Array list of new property need to be add to myObject
var others = [
  {0 : { key : 'hobby', value: 'reading' }},
  {1 :{ key : 'hobby', value: 'writing' }}
];
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer, can you have a look on my updated question ? maybe you will have some other ideas to help me accomplish that ?

Comment: Hi Fariz Azmi, You never add/append same key/value into any object. I think that the above solution which I have ping you. will help you. Because few days before, I was facing the same problem which you are facing now. I tried that code and it helped me.